# .Net ABP framework 6 - Intercept or extend new user creation API calls **Not Register**

Tags: abp

I have an ABP 6 Angular app. I would like to send an email ,when I create a new  user, asking them to confirm the email.  I have done similar thing when user Register themselves by overriding the default MVC page. But my user creation page is an angular page. Its posting the request to this API . https://localhost:xxxxx/api/identity/users. This is an ABP internal api and I'm unable to update it.  How can I extend this API to send an Email?

Answer (score 0):

You can also override a service or expose a service.

You can check the example in the dokumentation

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/2.5/Customizing-Application-Modules-Overriding-Services

In this example they override same method as you need.